# jquery FadeIn one element after FadeOut the previous div?

Tags: jquery, fadein

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".welcome").fadeOut(9500);
    $(".freelance").fadeIn(10000);
    $(".freelance").fadeOut(4500);
});
```

I want the welcome message to fadeOut slowly and then the other div to fadeIn its place and then fadeOut - obviously when the welcome box no longer exists.

```
<header>
    <h1 class="left"><a href="index.html"></a></h1>
    <div class="left yellowbox welcome"><p>Welcome to my portfolio.</p></div>
    <div class="left greenbox freelance"><p>I am currently available for for work, contact me below.</p></div>
</header>
```

Comment: The problem is.. both boxes appear at the same time and both then fade out at the same time/ish

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to call the additional `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut` inside of a callback function to the first one. All animation methods (and many others) in jQuery allow for callbacks:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".welcome").fadeOut(9500,function(){
        $(".freelance").fadeIn(10000, function(){
            $(".freelance").fadeOut(4500);
        });
    });
});
```

This will cause `.welcome` to fade out first. Once it's done fading out, `.freelance` will fade in. Once it's done fading in, it will then fade out.

Comment: I got it working by hiding it first using your code:

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 $(".freelance").hide();
 $(".welcome").fadeOut(6500,function(){
        $(".freelance").fadeIn(2500, function(){
            $(".freelance").fadeOut(4500);
        });
    });
});

Comment: I did that too so that it does not hide on the page load. Using .hide can make it appear during load and then disappear after load which makes a bad UX

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $(".welcome").fadeOut(9500, function() {
      $(".freelance").fadeIn(500, function () {
          $(".freelance").fadeOut(4500);
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: almost right, except you need the fadeOut of .freelance to be in the callback of the fadeIn call on .freelance. Your current code is both fading .freelance in and out at the exact same time.

Comment: @maxedison thank you, it still works the way it was meant tho, edited my answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this code might work

```
$(".welcome").fadeOut(9500).queue(function(next) { 
    $(".freelance").fadeIn(10000).queue(function(next) {
        $(".freelance").fadeOut(4500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want .delay()

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".welcome").delay(9000).fadeOut(9500);
    $(".freelance").delay(10000).fadeIn(10000);
    $(".freelance").delay(145000).fadeOut(4500);
});
```